# Triggers AWS Lambda Every Time a New Google Sheet Row is Added

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, google-sheets, aws-lambda

I have a google sheet that collects answer from a google form that ask user various question. Every time a form is submitted by user, a new row will be added to the google sheet.

I want to write AWS Lambda function such that every time a new response appear, the Lambda Function will run and append the new response to the RDS MySql Database.

I use Python to write script. Most of the stuff that I see out there are using node.js I'm not sure where to begin.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Google Sheets and Google Forms are not in the list of [services that Lambda reads events from](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-services.html#intro-core-components-event-sources), so the easiest solution would probably be to use an [installable "on form submit" trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) to run an Apps Script function that sends the data to your AWS Lambda instance through [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how your Google Sheet is configured, you can use the [onEdit()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) trigger in combination with this [Google Apps Script library](https://github.com/dxdc/aws-sdk-google-apps), which has full support for the AWS SDK.

Your final function could look something like this:

```js
// define your AWS configuration here (see dist/Config.js in the library example)

const AWS_CONFIG = {
  accessKey: 'AK0ZXZD0KGNG4KG6REBP', // use your own AWS key
  secretKey: 'EXrPgHC41HEW2YownLUnJLgh6bMsrmW1uva1ic24', // use your own AWS key
  region: 'us-east-1',
};

function initConfig(config) {
  AWS.config = new AWS.Config();
  AWS.config.update({
    region: config.region,
    sslEnabled: true,
    credentials: {
      accessKeyId: config.accessKey,
      secretAccessKey: config.secretKey,
    },
  });
}

// adopted from the (see dist/Examples.js in the library example)

async function invokeLambdaHelloWorld(payload) {
  initConfig(AWS_CONFIG);
  var result = await invokeLambda('helloWorld', payload);
  if (result === false) {
    return false;
  }

  return result;
}

async function onEdit(e) {
  // Set a comment on the edited cell to indicate when it was changed.
  const range = e.range;

  // Add some checks here to determine whether or not you need to call
  // the lambda function.

  // Prepare the payload

  const payload = {
    key1: 'value1',
    key2: 'value2',
    key3: 'value3',
  };

  // Call the lambda function and get the response

  const resp = await invokeLambdaHelloWorld(payload);
  Logger.log(resp);
}
```